# pip Packages -- Manual Download

Tags: python, pip

Coming from R to Python for some data science practice I want to download certain packages. Specifically I'm starting to look at Jinga2 and Jupyter for some work I will be following.

I'm behind a firewall and can't use pip or connect to any outer resource that isn't approved. Since it takes a lot of time to get those approved I am looking for a way to download the packages that I determine I need to run the specific commands I need. In R I can download the source from CRAN.

I'm looking for a CRAN like network for Python. Is there one?

Comment: Just download the wheel and install via pip locally. http://pythonwheels.com/

Comment: @CopyandPaste found a site that basically explains what those are which is cool. But there seems to be this possibility that a wheel may not exist. You don't know of a site that offers a repository of sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't sound like using pip is your problem; you just need to know how to install Python packages.

pip pulls all its packages from https://pypi.python.org/. You can go there yourself and find your package.

Download the .tar.gz file (it's source code) and extract the contents of that folder somewhere.

Now using your command line, navigate to that directory and run

```
python setup.py install
```

That's all!

Comment: So pypi.org would be the "CRAN" of python?

Comment: Yep. Anytime you pip ___, pip is just downloading it from pypi.python.org anyway so you're free to cut out the middleman if a proxy is getting in the way.

Answer (score 2):

you can download unofficial binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and install them using `pip install my_binary.whl`

Comment: You know of any discussion of possibly getting an official binary resource?

Comment: I think more of a repository.

Comment: That would be PyPI

Answer (score 0):

You Can install it using the below steps.

```
pip install <package_name> on your local machine
pip show <package_name>, this will contain link to source code with in Home-page field or download-url field.
Download the source code
Copy to the machine where you want to install it.
Run pip install <path/to/source/code>
```

However it is not a recommended way of doing things in production. You will have to get a local pip repo setup within your environment or get the pip source whitelisted on the firewall.